# isDrawerOpen returns false when drawer is open by sudden gesture

Tags: flutter

If you open the drawer by gesture in a sudden movement, the value of `Scaffold.of(ctx).isDrawerOpen` does get updated. If you open the drawer by clicking in the AppBar or by gesture pressing until the drawer is full opended, it will turn true, but with a sudden movement it does not turn true. It's affecting an `WillPopScope` from my app, when I'm checking if the drawer is open to not show a confirmation of leaving the current page to user.

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/evaldobratti/a6acdd64ea450beac19befde51493e85) with sample of the code and a [video](https://youtu.be/6oJp2zxYyqA) showing this strange behaviour.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. This is already an open issue on Flutter repo. You can find it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27674).

You can share your experience to help reproduce the bug as seen on your video.